# Arduino Python to Serial command

Tags: serial, python

I am trying to send commands via serial from Python to Arduino with the code below.

If I save this code in a dedicated python file "Stepper.py" (Python2.7 on Mac OSX) , the code runs successfully but nothing happens (the code does not trigger a motor connected to Arduino).

If I start terminal and run the same code from the interactive shell it works as expected.

How can I run it via a dedicated file ?

```
import serial 
import time

ser = serial.Serial(port="/dev/cu.usbmodem144231", baudrate=9600, timeout = 0)
ser.write("200+")
time.sleep(1)
print ser.read()
```

Comment: You need to wait after opening the serial port for the board to finish resetting and the bootloader to run and exit before you can send any commands.

Comment: You are the man !!! Awesome works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Majenkos comment (above) solved the problem:

"You need to wait after opening the serial port for the board to finish resetting and the bootloader to run and exit before you can send any commands."

```
import serial 
import time

ser = serial.Serial(port="/dev/cu.usbmodem144231", baudrate=9600, timeout = 0)
time.sleep(1)
ser.write("200+")
print ser.read()
```